# How to reconcile monorepo with multiple tsconfig.json each having its own paths?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

We have a codebase setup like so:

```
-A
--utils
---index.ts
--index.ts
--tsconfig.json
-B
--utils
---index.ts
--index.ts
--tsconfig.json
-tsconfig.json
```

Our root `tsconfig.json` contains the following:

```
    "paths": {
      "A/*": ["A/*"],
      "B/*": ["B/*"],
    },
```

Each package's `tsconfig.json` contains the following:

```
    "paths": {
      "utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
    },
```

This works for our current purposes, since we currently only use TS for type checking but we actually generate builds with Babel, which has a similar setup in the `alias` property of the various `.babelrc` files.

We are looking to start running code using `ts-node` (or an equivalent) and have run into the issue that at runtime, TS has no idea how to resolve modules. For example:

```
// A/index.ts
import { someUtil } from 'utils'
export const someFunc() => someUtil();
```

```
// B/index.ts
import { someFunc } from 'A';
```

When we run `npx ts-node ./B/index.ts` we get an error saying `Cannot find modules 'utils'.

We know that we can get this working by hoisting everything to the root `tsconfig.json`, but it seems superfluous to have to `import { someUtil } from 'A/utils` when you are already in package A.

Is there a way to use paths in the manner that we have? We have also read a bit about project references and tried that but it didn't seem to get us anywhere.

Answer (score 13):

Inside the `tsconfig.json` file in each of the projects you should use `extends` on the root `tsconfig` like this:

```json
// A/tsconfig.json
{
 "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
 ...
}
```

Thay way all the subprojects will inherit the paths from other general packages.

I think you can even define the `utils` path on the root, that way you won't have to repeat that either.

More about the `extends` option here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#tsconfig-bases

**UPDATE**

Also you need to use this lib:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths

and inside the `package.json` in the `ts-node` script in the `scripts` property you use: `ts-node ... -r tsconfig-paths/register ... index.ts`.

This lib will read the packages in `ts-config.json` and place them in `node_modules`, so your other packages can find them when you run with node or ts-node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already extend the root tsconfig in all of our sub-configs, and using `tsconfig-paths` didn't seem to work for us: packages could reach into other packages, but the named paths within each package no longer work

Comment: `tsconfig-paths` will load all your packages in the root `tsconfig.json` to node-modules, so it will work for the relative paths.

Comment: inside each package.json you have to place the -r tsconfig-paths/register option in the command you use to run each project

Comment: the named paths inside each package might better be referenced by the `path` you defined in the root `tsconfig.json` or by referencing them with their relative path and not the alias

Comment: Yeah, hoping to avoid using relative paths. I fully agree it would be better to define all `paths` in the root `tsconfig.json` but unfortunately there are path name clashes within the sub-packages (they each define a `utils` folder for example) that would be a pain to refactor. Was hoping there might be an easier way around doing all of that, thus this question :) Will try the `-r tsconfig-paths/register` within each package later, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not rude or unhelpful to suggest what you're trying to do might make no sense.

From the point of view of package A, './utils' can be different from the './utils' that package B sees - since they have a different filesystem 'root'. However, the attempt to alias two different './utils' paths as 'utils' from the point of view of BOTH packages creates an inevitable collision.

I am far from sure there's any value in doing this either. I would personally drop the aliasing of folders "./utils" to top-level aliases "utils" and then I think your issues will go away. Probably what you want on a per-package basis is specific `includes`, and for the 'local' utils for each package to be addressed relatively to the package...

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["index.ts", "utils/index.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Not rude at all, it's certainly possible I'm going about this all wrong. "for the 'local' utils for each package to be addressed relatively to the package..." Yes, that's exactly what we want, the issue is that we've had trouble doing that when one package calls code from another package. Will look into and play around more with `include`, thanks!